# Get nodes of specific type in Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

So I'm using a networkX graph to represent some information. This information is represented by different object types (for example, ColorNode and ShapeNode).

Some of the processing that is done on this graph requires me to extract out a specific type of node. Every time I need to do this, I do something along the lines of the code below.

```
colornodes = []
for node in graph.nodes():
    if isinstance(node, ColorNode):
        colornodes.append()
```

While this works, I feel like this is a situation that would arise often when working with graphs and I am re-inventing the wheel there.
Essentially, I would like to know if there is a nicer way of doing this.

Comment: @Joel thanks for pointing that out. If I click "that solved my problem" would question still be viewable by others? Asking primarily because the alternate method in Kikohs answer is quite valuable and I wouldn't want to loose that.

Comment: Yes - it would look something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231644/js-replace-not-working-on-string?lq=1  This question and its answers would remain and a link to the other page would appear prominently (and the other page would have a link on the sidebar to this page).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of defining your own type and always check with `isinstance` (which is painfully slow) I suggest another approach.

You can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644684/best-practices-for-querying-graphs-by-edge-and-node-attributes-in-networkx) for the classic node/edge filtering.

However I found **another trick** which may come handy for your specific case.

If you define an attribute that represents the node type, you can query nodes having that specific attribute using
the builtin `get_node_attributes` function. The trick is that it only returns nodes that really define the attribute:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.complete_graph(10)
G.node[0]['ColorNode'] = True  # right-hand side value is irrelevant for the lookup
G.node[1]['ColorNode'] = True
G.node[2]['ShapeNode'] = True
G.node[3]['ShapeNode'] = True

shape_nodes = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'ShapeNode').keys()
color_nodes = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'ColorNode').keys()

print('Shape node ids: {}'.format(shape_nodes))
print('Color node ids: {}'.format(color_nodes))
```

Output:

```
Shape node ids: [2, 3]
Color node ids: [0, 1]
```

Of course if your graph is big or static, you should keep the id lists for fast querying!

Comment: Cheers, thats a pretty neat idea!

Answer (score -4):

instead of `graph.nodes()`, 
you can use xpath.

Comment: Sorry, I could be missing something obvious here, but is xpath something that is part of networkx? I can't seem to find anything in the networkx doucmentation related to xpath

Comment: yes like ---- for node in graph.xpath(.... )

Comment: Would you clarify your answer @sneha

Comment: @sneha if `graph` is a networkx graph, then `graph.xpath` is undefined.

Comment: for example:def edges():
    for node in root.xpath('//n:node', namespaces = { 'n' : root.nsmap[None] }):
        node_id = int(node.attrib['id'])
        for edge in node.xpath('./n:children/n:nodeRef/@rid', namespaces = { 'n' : root.nsmap[None] }):
            yield (node_id, int(edge))