# Organizing a graph by node types: What is the most efficient way to collect nodes by type?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

## Problem

I'm creating a graph with many nodes where each node can represent one of many types of things. 5 cat nodes, 30 dog nodes, 40 people nodes, etc...

I'm currently assigning a 'node_type' attribute to each node and filtering over all nodes to collect nodes of a given type. I have to do this operation a lot and it feels very expensive and wrong. I've looked into bipartite graphs but they only support two groupings of nodes.

## Question

What is the best, most efficient way to organize and collect nodes of a given type?

I've looked at similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644684/best-practices-for-querying-graphs-by-edge-and-node-attributes-in-networkx) but this use case seems too common for a full graph search to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning each node a value and having to iterate over every single one when using them, why not just have lists for each node type?

Comment: I've thought about that, and it's a perfectly fine idea and probably what I'll end up with but I just want to know whether NetworkX has the concept of node types or buckets. If not, then I feel that my assumptions about how NetworkX is intended to be used are wrong.

(Edit: I'll give the post a couple more days and then I'll give you the bounty if no better answer is submitted )